# Hide Parent View, When navigate to child view or Hide parent view in nested child view in aurelia

Tags: aurelia

This is my App.js

```
export class App {
configureRouter(config, router) {
this.router = router;
config.title = 'Aurelia';
config.map([
  { route: ['', 'home'], name: 'home', moduleId: 'home', nav: true, breadcrumb: true, title: 'HOME'},
  { route: 'about', name: 'about', moduleId: 'about', nav: true, breadcrumb: true, title: 'About Us'},
  { route: 'products', name: 'products', moduleId: 'products', nav: true, breadcrumb: true, title: 'Products'},
  { route: 'services', name: 'services', moduleId: 'services', nav: true, breadcrumb: true, title: 'Services'},
  { route: 'contact', name: 'contact', moduleId: 'contact', nav: true, breadcrumb: true, title: 'Contact'}
]);
}
}
```

And in app.html

```
<template>
<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
<aurelia-crumbs config.bind="config"></aurelia-crumbs>
<h1 class="text-center">Wel Come to my company</h1>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li repeat.for="route of router.navigation" class="${route.isActive ? 'active' : ''}">
          <a href.bind="route.href">${route.title}</a>  
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav> 
<router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

When i goto products page, i have child routes for it and this is how my products.js looks like

```
export class Products {
configureRouter(config, router) {
  this.router = router;
  config.title = 'Aurelia';
  config.map([
    { route: ['','product1'], name: 'product1', moduleId: 'product1', nav: true, breadcrumb: true, title: 'Product 1'},
    { route: 'product2', name: 'product2', moduleId: 'product2', nav: true, breadcrumb: true, title: 'Product 2'}
  ]);
}
```

}

And products.html is

```
<template>
<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
<h1 class="text-center">Products</h1>
<div>
    <ul>
       <li repeat.for = "row of router.navigation">
          <a href.bind = "row.href">${row.title}</a>
       </li>
    </ul> 
</div>

<router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

And again in my product2, I have other child routes

here is  product2.js

```
export class Product2 {
configureRouter(config, router) {
  this.router = router;
  config.title = 'Aurelia';
  config.map([
    { route: ['','product_2_1'], name: 'product_2_1', moduleId: 'product_2_1', nav: true, breadcrumb: true, title: 'Product_2_1'},
    { route: 'product_2_2', name: 'product_2_2', moduleId: 'product_2_2', nav: true, breadcrumb: true, title: 'Product_2_2'}
  ]);
}
```

}

And product2.html is

```
<template>
<require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
<h1 class="text-center">Product2</h1>
<div>
    <ul>
       <li repeat.for = "row of router.navigation">
          <a href.bind = "row.href">${row.title}</a>
       </li>
    </ul> 
</div>

<router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

So my problem here is, when i navigate to product_2_2, i can see the content of product and product2 pages. I don't want that, instead when i click on product_2_2, i want only product_2_2 content to displayed, by hiding product and product2 content. I mean how can i hide of view of product and product2 pages and these pages content is in a separate element.

Comment: if you hide the parent view then the child view which is _composed_ inside the parent view also gets hidden. You could however, put the contents of parent view(excluding the child part) which you want hidden in a div and hide them upon showing the child view. But this seems really bad tbh. If you share your code and show what you're trying to do it'd be better.

Comment: @adiga my requirement here is,  when i navigate from parent to child, as the child view will be in parent, so i don't want to hide parent view, in a bad manner, instead, I'm DI parent to child and from child I'm trying to hide the parent content, which is present in separate div of parent template. I don't know is this the correct or not. Please do suggest any other better as per norms